# Does the ATF have jurisdiction over electromagnetic projecitle weapons such as rail and coilguns?

Tags: united-states, regulations, weapons

I had a rather stupid argument with a gentleman. He claimed the ATF had no jurisdiction on magnetic-propelled projectile weapons, such as the gauss rifle, railgun, or coilguns. I argued they consider tasers as firearms, he said it was an exception to the rule and only chemical propelled projectile weapons were otherwise considered as *fire* arms.

We did some searching in our phones but found no definite evidence.

I did find the particular [taser rule](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/docs/ruling/1976-6-tasers-firearms), which he thought reinforced his stance. Especially the part where an explosive is required.

> Tasers as Firearms (25.14 KB) A hand-held device designed to expel by means of an explosive two electrical contacts (barbs) connected by two wires attached to a high voltage source in the device classified as a firearm.

We parted right after that, leaving me with this doubt. As a corollary, are they even allowed for civilians?

Comment: It might be a "destructive device" under [26 USC 5845(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/5845).  I'm not sure of the regulatory consequences, though.

Comment: you need to read the definition of firearm - in Germany a railgun is a firearm, as is a potato cannon or a crossbow, but a bow is not, because the definition of firearm lingers on *storing* energy without human interaction in some form or another.

Comment: @NateEldredge That definition makes it sound like railguns are only firearms if they are either machineguns or destructive devices. Keep them semi-automatic and with a barrel diameter of less than one half of an inch and you're good to go.